# Python keep N images for each group of images

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, image, directory

I have a list of image path as follows:

```
['images/001_1.png', 'images/001_5.png', 'images/001_6.png', 'images/123_3.png', 'images/123_9.png', 'images/123_12.png']
```

In this example, there are two groups of images (001_#.png & 123_#.png). I want to keep N images ***randomly*** for each group (where N = 1 for example).

I want to write a python function that reads the above array and returns another array as an output. So, my expected output array will be something like below:

```
['images/001_1.png', 'images/123_9.png']
```

I really appreciate it if anyone could help me with this. Thank you in advance.